# Can I tell if a stored procedure has executed against a particular database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, audit, log

As a result of a release a database is behaving "unusually".   I suspect a stored procedure was missed during a recent release, however my DBA is telling me 100% it was executed.

Is there any way to definitively prove it was or wasn't?

Comment: are you talking about release scripts or stored procedures inside database?

Comment: Existing sp's within the db, but needed to be run to update some settings after a release (and I don't think was!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(emphasis added)

> Is there any way to **definitively prove** it was/wasn't

No, there is no way to prove in any *definite* way that it has been executed, outside of coding the stored procedure to do something like insert a record into a log table showing that it had been executed. In your particular case, this would also require a time machine in order to put that into place, and I do not believe that those are even possible to create in the first place :-(.

There are DMVs which can track executions, but they get cleared out for various reasons:

- service restart
- DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL')
- memory pressure
- maybe others

Of course, if you *do* see it in any DMV, that does prove that it *was* executed, but you better take a screen shot because it might be gone the next time you run that query to show someone that it is there ;-). However, not finding it in a DMV does not prove that it was never executed.

So, along with the query suggested by @TheGameiswar, you could also try the following:

```
SELECT qplan.[objectid], qplan.[dbid], OBJECT_NAME(qplan.[objectid], qplan.[dbid])
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cplan
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cplan.[plan_handle]) qplan
WHERE qplan.[objectid] IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from SQL Server 2008,use can <kbd>[sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc280701.aspx)</kbd> which gives you the status  on when was the stored procedure last executed

```
select db_name(database_id) as dbname,last_execution_time 
from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
```